# Show dropdown menu on click over other close button, only on single element Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript and still trying to understand how events and selectors work.

I have a close button and once I click on it, I want a single dropdown to pop-down according to the clicked card.

I would like to do this by toggling a class and the styles have been already set up on that class.

The error that I am getting is as follow: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined;

If I use the event handler as normal, it will pull down all drop down menus and that is not my goal.

My code is below:

HTML

```
    <section id="wrapper">
    <div class="headline">
        <span class="promoted-stories">Promoted stories</span>
        <span class="taboola-link"><a href="#">Sponsored Links by Taboola</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
        <article class="card">
            <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/Couple.jpg" alt="3 Reasons Why You Haven't Found Your Match Yet">
                <a href="#" class="close"></a><!-- close button -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                </ul>
            </figure>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">3 Reasons Why You Haven't Found Your Match Yet</h2>
                <p class="category">Dating life</p>
            </div><!-- .card-content -->
        </article><!-- .card -->
        <article class="card">
            <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/royals.jpg" alt="Harry And Meghan Announce Baby On The Way">
                <a href="#" class="close"></a><!-- close button -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                </ul>
            </figure>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Harry And Meghan Announce Baby On The Way</h2>
                <p class="category">Royals</p>
            </div><!-- .card-content -->
        </article><!-- .card -->
        <article class="card">
            <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/stage.jpg" alt="Things Get Seriously Real As RuPaul Cast Open Up">
                <a href="#" class="close"></a><!-- close button -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                </ul>
            </figure>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Things Get Seriously Real As RuPaul Cast Open Up</h2>
                <p class="category">Celebrities</p>
            </div><!-- .card-content -->
        </article><!-- .card -->
        <article class="card">
            <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/circus.jpg" alt="A Tiger Collapsed In A Russian Circus Mid-Show">
                <a href="#" class="close"></a><!-- close button -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                </ul>
            </figure>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">A Tiger Collapsed In A Russian Circus Mid-Show</h2>
                <p class="category">Circus</p>
            </div><!-- .card-content -->
        </article><!-- .card -->
        <article class="card">
            <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/people.jpg" alt="Engagement On The Cards For Jack And Dani">
                <a href="#" class="close"></a><!-- close button -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                </ul>
            </figure>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Engagement On The Cards For Jack And Dani</h2>
                <p class="category">Dating life</p>
            </div><!-- .card-content -->
        </article><!-- .card -->
        <article class="card">
            <a class="overlay" href="#overlay-link"></a>
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <img src="images/atwood.jpg" alt="Attwood Hits Back At Rumours Of Dani Dyer Fued">
                <a href="#" class="close"></a><!-- close button -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                    <li>Menu</li>
                </ul>
            </figure>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Attwood Hits Back At Rumours Of Dani Dyer Fued</h2>
                <p class="category">Gossip</p>
            </div><!-- .card-content -->
        </article><!-- .card -->
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
<pre>* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

#wrapper {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 880px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.headline {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.headline .promoted-stories {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #404040;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.headline .taboola-link a {
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: right;
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.cards {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    display: block;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin: 1%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 31.33333333%;
    flex: 0 0 31.33333333%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
    position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
    transform: translate(0, -2px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.card .thumbnail {
    display: block;
    height: 140px;
}

.card img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    -o-object-position: 50% 50%;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}

.card-content {
    padding: 5px 10px 25px;
}

.card .card-content .card-title {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-height: 72px;
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card .card-content .category {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 11.0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 52px;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 15px;
    top: 5px;
    height: 15px;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    right: 0;
    content: ' ';
    height: 15px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.close:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.card a.close {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.4s linear;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.4s linear;
}

.card:hover a.close {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Change the opacity of just the selected element */
.fade {
    opacity: .3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .card {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 48%;
        flex: 0 0 48%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .card {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 98%;
        flex: 0 0 98%;
        margin: 2%;
    }

    .card .thumbnail {
        height: 170px;
    }
}
</pre>
```

Javascript

```
(function() {
            let closeButtons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".close"));
            closeButtons.forEach(function(button) {
                button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    let elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul'));
                    elements.forEach(function(e) {
                        e.target.classList.toggle('show');
                    });
                });
            });
        })();
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this script so I can achieve my final goal?

No jQuery allowed.

Comment: It's possible your code is being invoked before the DOM is finished rendering your buttons. Please place the script tag at the end of the htmll document before the body closing tag and test it out.

Comment: `elements` contains all ul elements on the page, which you then toggle.  It would seem you only want to toggle the single ul located after the clicked button.

Comment: Hi James, yes this is exactly my goal. However, if I use elements, it will toggle them all and this is why I am using e.target but it does not work. Any idea what I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to toggle only the `ul` within the same `figure` as the clicked button try this:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let figure = this.parentNode; // locate the figure element surrounding the clicked button
  let targetUL = figure.querySelector("ul"); // get its ul
  targetUL.classList.toggle("show");
});
```

Which could be compressed to

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("show");
});
```